# How can I get the "lein repl" history to work in cygwin?

Tags: clojure, cygwin, leiningen

I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7 and the latest lein, but when I am in the repl, pressing up and down moves me around the repl console instead of showing me history (which is what I expect).  I've googled around and seen that this is related to using jline instead of readline (whatever that means) but I don't know how to use this information to fix my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach to the one you suggested would be to install `rlwrap` which is available in Cygwin. This will give you [Readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) capabilities (eg. command history search and navigation) to any interactive command line application. If you've used bash for any length of time you will know what these capabilities are.

You will need to start the applications as parameters to the readline wrapper but this can be hidden away using aliases or functions as appropriate:

```
rlwrap lein repl
```

The benefit of using rlwrap over your suggestion is that it can add this capabilities to more than just the specific case of the repl.

Comment: Very interesting.  I think I'll try that out and report back.  This is good to know even for non-lein issues.

Comment: Exactly. At work we have been using it with `sqlplus` for so long that people have forgotten that sqlplus doesn't natively provide this functionality.

Comment: I like this solution better than what I found so I marked it as the answer.  Thanks

Comment: @tieTYT Excellent. Glad to hear you have found it useful.

Comment: You know I'm noticing that every `lein repl` I ctrl+c out of leaves a java.exe behind.  Do you experience this same problem?

Comment: @tieTYT I'm not seeing that happening but I can see that [others have](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leiningen/pVgraIJhMaI/crejYJSJ2TAJ). Not sure how relevant that is though as it's from a year ago.

Answer (score 5):

[I found the answer here:](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/850)

> I modified the lein startup script to call stty and set jline.terminal, and it seems to work:

```
stty -icanon min 1 -echo
$LEIN_JAVA_CMD \
    -client -XX:+TieredCompilation \
    -Djline.terminal=jline.UnixTerminal \
    $LEIN_JVM_OPTS \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
    -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.easy=false \
    -Dleiningen.original.pwd="$ORIGINAL_PWD" \
    -Dleiningen.trampoline-file="$TRAMPOLINE_FILE" \
    -cp "$CLASSPATH" \
    clojure.main -m leiningen.core.main "$@"
EXIT_CODE=$?
stty icanon echo
```

I modified that section in the lein script and now up = history.